# Как запустить сервис, так чтобы окно текущего приложения (чужого) не закрылось

Tags: java, android, service

При включенном чужом приложении (например, запущен браузер) пользователь тыкает в "Список недавно использованных приложений", выбирает оттуда мое приложение и мое приложение открывается поверх текущего приложения (выводится картинка размером в часть экрана).

Сделано следующим образом: запускаю прозрачную `activity`, которая вызывает сервис, который выводит картинку. При запуске с компа (через USB) все срабатывает нормально, при запуске с телефона (из списка недавно использованных приложений) картинка появляется поверх чужого приложения (как и задумывалось), после чего, меньше чем через секунду, чужое приложение закрывается (т.е. выскакивает главный экран, поверх которого размещена моя картинка).

Что делаю не так?

Comment: Попробуй поменять launchMode  у активити, которое ты запускаешь.
Попробуй прописать "android:launchMode="singleTop""